# How to redirect from https://www.* to https://* with golang library net/http

Tags: go, ssl, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all requests to the same url with the golang library net/http.

Currently working:

- http://DOMAIN -> https://DOMAIN
- http://www.DOMAIN -> https://DOMAIN

Not yet working:

- https://www.DOMAIN -> https://DOMAIN

Both urls return the same content for all requested resources, but that doesn't matter for session cookies.

My minimal code:

```
    func listenAndHandle() {
        http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))
        http.HandleFunc("/", handle.PageIndex)

        go func() {
            if err := http.ListenAndServe(":80", http.HandlerFunc(redirectTLS)); err != nil {
                handle.Lv.Println("ListenAndServe error:", err)
            }
        }()

        handle.Lv.Println(http.ListenAndServeTLS(database.Config.PORT, database.Config.TLScertfile,
    database.Config.TLSkeyfile, nil))
    }

    func redirectTLS(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if strings.Contains(r.Host, "www.") {
            u := *r.URL
            u.Host = strings.Replace(r.Host, "www.", "", 1)
            u.Scheme = "https"
            http.Redirect(w, r, u.String(), http.StatusFound)
            return
        }
        http.Redirect(w, r, database.Config.TLSurl+r.RequestURI, http.StatusMovedPermanently)
    }
```

I'm not really interested in adding another library to solve this one problem, everything else works just fine with the golang default net/http.

Comment: Try by *not* using `r.Host` and instead use `r.URL.Host` exclusively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the TLS server handler with a handler that either redirects to the bare domain or delegates to the original handler.

The code in the question uses [http.DefaultServeMux](https://godoc.org/net/http#DefaultServeMux) as the TLS server the handler.  Here's a handler function that either redirects or calls through to http.DefaultServeMux:

```
func redirectWWW(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if strings.HasPrefix(r.Host, "www.") {
        u := *r.URL
        u.Scheme = "https"
        u.Host = strings.TrimPrefix(r.Host, "www.")
        http.Redirect(w, r, u.String(), http.StatusFound)
        return
    }
    http.DefaultServeMux.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

Use this handler in the TLS server:

```
    handle.Lv.Println(http.ListenAndServeTLS(database.Config.PORT, database.Config.TLScertfile,
database.Config.TLSkeyfile, http.HandlerFunc(redirectWWW)))
```

Comment: Thank you. When I tried this, I initially got CORS errors for all requests stating that Access-Control-Allow-Origin has not being set. By chance I reregistered my service worker, which caches most of my responses, and for the moment it works. Unfortunately I don't understand what exactly went wrong.